# NgModel isn't reflecting the selected value from a dropdown whose values get populated based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

When the component is loaded, I want `mainTask` and `mainJob` to be reflected as a selection in the dropdown, `mainTask` is reflected as expected but `mainJob` isnt updated in the UI. However, if I manually select a value in UI from the `taskList`, `mainJob` is updated accordingly. Looks like `mainJob` isn't getting reflected because the jobList dropdown is triggered by the selection of `mainTask`. How can I correct my code?

html file

```
<mat-form-field>
              <mat-select [(ngModel)]="mainTask">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let task of taskList"
                            [value]="task"
                            (click)="getJobs()">
                  {{task}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
              <mat-select [(ngModel)]="mainJob">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let job of jobList"
                            [value]="job">
                  {{job}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

ts file

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.taskList = ['task1','task2','task3'];
    this.jobList = ['job1','job2','job3'];
    this.mainTask = 'task2';
    this.mainJob = 'job2';
}
getJobs():void {
    if(mainTask){
       const jobIndex = this.taskList.indexOf(this.mainTask);
       this.jobList.splice(0, jobIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what you are trying to achieve with `this.jobList.splice(0, jobIndex)`. I think you meant `this.mainJob = this.jobList[jobIndex]`

Comment: I am deleting all the values in the array `jobList` from the start of the array to `mainTask` index present in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, the mainJob is selected only when getjobs() function is called,

you can assign a value to mainJob in a component like

```
mainJob:string = 'job2';
```

and not in ngOnIt. check this plunker [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-vwjz7b?file=app/app.component.ts)